# tidyverse: matching specific dates to event periods

Tags: r, vlookup, tidyverse

I've got dates that I want to match with events for which I only have the start date.  As a simplified reprex, say I'd like to figure out who was president during certain events, but I only have inauguration dates.

```
pres <- data.frame(pres = c("Ronald Reagan", "George H. W. Bush", 
                            "Bill Clinton", "George W. Bush", "Barack 
                             Obama", "Donald Trump"), 
                     inaugdate = structure(c(4037, 6959, 8420, 11342, 14264, 
                                             17186), class = "Date"))

events <- data.frame(event = c("Challenger explosion", "Chernobyl 
                                explosion", "Hurricane Katrina", "9-11"), 
                      date = structure(c(5871, 5959, 13024, 11576), class = "Date"))
```

Obviously, a simple left_join won't work because the events didn't happen on inauguration days.

```
events %>%
      left_join(pres, by = c("date" = "inaugdate"))
```

In Excel, vlookup used to give you an option of true (match closest previous) or false (match exact).  Is there something similar in the tidyverse?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way to achieve the desired result, although it could probably be prettied up a bit. You can create intervals, which are a class provided by `lubridate` to specify timespans with a particular start and end time. This comes with the `%within%` operator to see if a date is in that interval. So we can first create this interval and make the `pres` column a character type so we can index it properly. Then, we iterate over the event dates with `map_chr`, using a function that says "check if this date is in each interval, get the index of the one that it is actually in (with `which`), and return the president corresponding to that". Obviously this requires that each date is found in only one interval, else this will fail.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

pres <- data.frame(pres = c("Ronald Reagan", "George H. W. Bush", 
                            "Bill Clinton", "George W. Bush",
                            "Barack Obama", "Donald Trump"), 
                   inaugdate = structure(c(4037, 6959, 8420, 11342, 14264, 
                                           17186), class = "Date"))

events <- data.frame(event = c("Challenger explosion", "Chernobyl explosion",
                               "Hurricane Katrina", "9-11"), 
                     date = structure(c(5871, 5959, 13024, 11576), class = "Date"))

pres2 <- pres %>%
  mutate(
    presidency = interval(inaugdate, lead(inaugdate, default = today())),
    pres = as.character(pres)
  )
events %>%
  mutate(pres = map_chr(date, ~ pres2$pres[which(. %within% pres2$presidency)]))
#>                  event       date           pres
#> 1 Challenger explosion 1986-01-28  Ronald Reagan
#> 2  Chernobyl explosion 1986-04-26  Ronald Reagan
#> 3    Hurricane Katrina 2005-08-29 George W. Bush
#> 4                 9-11 2001-09-11 George W. Bush
```

<sup>Created on 2019-02-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the most efficient, but we can use an inequality join with `sqldf`:

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf('select a.event, a.date, b.pres
      from events a 
      left join pres b
      on a.date >= b.inaugdate
      group by a.event 
      having min(a.date - b.inaugdate)
      order by date, event')
```

**Output:**

```
                 event       date           pres
1 Challenger explosion 1986-01-28  Ronald Reagan
2  Chernobyl explosion 1986-04-26  Ronald Reagan
3                 9-11 2001-09-11 George W. Bush
4    Hurricane Katrina 2005-08-29 George W. Bush
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not efficient (depending on number of rows and columns) but another way to solve the problem.

```
library(dplyr) 

pres <- data.frame(pres = c("Ronald Reagan", "George H. W. Bush", 
                            "Bill Clinton", "George W. Bush", "Barack Obama", "Donald Trump"), 
                   inaugdate = structure(c(4037, 6959, 8420, 11342, 14264, 
                                           17186), class = "Date")) %>% 
                  #lead date to get interval
                  mutate(enddt = lead(inaugdate, default = Sys.Date())-1)

events <- data.frame(event = c("Challenger explosion", "Chernobyl explosion", "Hurricane Katrina", "9-11"), 
                     date = structure(c(5871, 5959, 13024, 11576), class = "Date"))          
#get every combination of rows
newdf <- merge(pres,events,all = TRUE) %>% 
  filter(date >= inaugdate, date < enddt)
```